# PHP Deprecated: Function create_function()

Tags: php, function, deprecated, create-function

Im getting PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function()

with the following code:

```
function fetch_sentence_case($text)
{
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '#(^|\.\s+|\:\s+|\!\s+|\?\s+)[a-z]#',
        create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'),
        vbstrtolower($text)
    );
}
```

I tried

```
function fetch_sentence_case($text)
{
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '#(^|\.\s+|\:\s+|\!\s+|\?\s+)[a-z]#',
        function($matches) { return strtoupper($matches[0]; },
        vbstrtolower($text)
    );
}
```

but it does not work.

???

Comment: It isn't due to the syntax error of missing parenthesis, e.g. strtoupper($matches[0]); ?

Answer (score 0):

I do realize you're probably constrained to this method due to PHP version, though please look into [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php).

Wadih's comment above is correct. You're missing parenthesis.